# Updated from 12.04 to 13.10, now wireless won't work and freezes my laptop

Tags: 12.04, wireless, 13.10, updates

I'm using a Toshiba Satellite with dual boot (Ubuntu and Windows 7). I just updated from 12.04 to 13.10, and everything seemed to be working fine. Wireless did connect right after the first reboot, but it was extremely slow and trying to access wireless options didn't work - it acted as if wireless connection was disabled. So I tried disabling it and re-enabling, but Ubuntu crashed and dumped a bunch of stuff on the screen. I took a photo of the dump (I'm apologize for the quality):
[image]

After that I had to force a reboot, as it became unresponsive. Does anyone know what this is, how to solve it, or at least seen this before?

Comment: Could be anything. I suggest you boot the 13.10 live usb and see if it working. If so, I would suggest you do a fresh install. If not we need a lot more information including your hardware. Debugging a failed upgrade takes much more time then a fresh install.

Comment: I had to install a fresh 13.10 after all.